# How do you tell django which python version to use?

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

The default version of python on centos is 2.6 and I am using a feature in my django app that requires 2.7 . Where would I specify which version to use?

The python path for 2.7 is at /usr/local/bin/python2.7

The webserver I am using is apache. I have tried a few different things but have not had much luck. Any ideas?

Comment: How does django run from apache? WSGI? What's in your config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `virtualenv` (hint: you should), you can specify the python version when creating the environment:

```
virtualenv --python=python2.7 <your_venv_name>
```

For `mod_wsgi`, have a look in the apache modules directory. I have no experience with centos, but on Debian, in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules`, you can choose the python version by modifying the `mod_wsgi.so` symlink (this is on debian oldstable):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Feb 10  2011 mod_wsgi.so -> mod_wsgi.so-2.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151648 Sep 26  2010 mod_wsgi.so-2.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151680 Sep 26  2010 mod_wsgi.so-2.6
```

(For reference: for python3, you need to install a separate package, `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`)

I imagine centos has something similar. If there isn't, you need to either find a `mod_wsgi` package built against python 2.7, or rebuild `mod_wsgi` from source against the right python version.